# bundles based on areas in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to bundle one js file for each area and I am able to do it. But, the problem is to refer . 
I dont want to refer all areas js in _Layout.cshtml because it is going to load all areas js files.

I can change js based on the area but our _layout will load only once from there it is only ajax calls.

Which is the right place to refer the js area wise in my case ?

Comment: while including js files in layout page ... you can use case statement and specify your area's in case statement and include js accordingly as per area's in layout page....

Comment: no - do not do that , i'll get answer (that will work) but using conditional cases all over in views is frowned upon

Answer (score 1):

this is what sections are for:

_Layout.cshtml

```
   <head>
          @RenderSection("head", false)
     ...
   </head>
```

the false parameter means not required, that is what you want in this case.

then in your child view

```
      @section head{
        @Bundle.Scripts.Add("my scripts location");
      }
```

note that the children get rendered first in MVC framework, so if there is javascript in this view it will start to be executed before the layout.   So always use Document Load event or Window Ready ,  self executing code will fail if it is dependent on the scripts referenced in the Layout

or you can try something like this:

store the area you are in somewhere in your ViewModel , I'll use the ViewBag just for the example.  Then create a separate bundle of scripts for each area whereever you register your bundles .  Then you can do something like

```
  @Bundle.Scripts.Add("/scripts/" + ViewBag.Area + "/myscripts");
```

Comment: Thanks Scott..I don't want to reference it in the child view.I just want to refer it once for an area..I tried it in _viewstart but no luck.